# separating container component from presentational component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i just started building apps with react native and created a basic login function with the view and the login function on the same page called `HomeScreen.js` . But i've read article from the web and i'm told its best to seperate the logic code from the view, that the functions must be on a seperate page and the views on a different page as well. Please i'll need help on how to do that

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ActivityIndicator, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Icon, Header, Left, Content, Container, Form, Input, Item, Button, Label, Toast} from 'native-base'
import SettingsScreen from './SettingsScreen';



class HomeScreen extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            showLoader: false,
        }
    }


    static navigationOptions={
        header: null,
        drawerIcon:(
            <Image source={require('../assets/imgs/logo.jpg')}
            style={{height:24, width:24}}/>
        )
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <Container>
        <Header>
            <Left>
                <Icon name="ios-menu" onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}/>
            </Left>
        </Header>

        <Content style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}>
        <Content style={{alignContent:"center", top:100}}>

        { <Image  source={require('../assets/imgs/logo.jpg')}
        style={{height:200, width:200, alignSelf:"center"}}/> }

        <Form>
            <Item stackedLabel>
            <Label >
                Username
            </Label>
            <Input onChangeText={(text=>this.setState({userName:text}))} autoCapitalize = 'none'/>
            </Item>

            <Item stackedLabel last>
            <Label >
                Password
            </Label>
            <Input onChangeText={(text=>this.setState({passWord:text}))}  secureTextEntry={true}  />
            </Item>

            <Content style={{padding:20}}>
            <Button onPress={this.userLogin.bind(this)} iconRight block  primary disabled={!this.state.userName} disabled={!this.state.passWord}>
                <Icon name='arrow-forward' />
                <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Login</Text>
            </Button>
            </Content>

            <Content>
                <ActivityIndicator style={{padding:5}}
                animating={this.state.showLoader}
                size="small"
                />
            </Content>

        </Form>

        </Content>
        </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }

  userLogin(){ 
      this.setState({showLoader: true});
      fetch('http://api_endpoint.com/login.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body :JSON.stringify({
            username: this.state.userName,
            password: this.state.passWord
          })
      }).then((response)=>{
        return response.json()
      }).then((response)=>{
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.message))
          this.setState({showLoader: false})
          if(response.message==='0'){
            Toast.show({
                text: "Wrong Username or Password",
                buttonText: "Try Again",
                type: "danger",
                duration: 4000
              })
          }else{
            this.props.navigation.push('Settings');
          }
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.setState({showLoader: false})
        Alert.alert(
            'Error!',
            'Connection Failed, Try again later',
            [
              {text: 'Ok'}
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          )

      });
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done a great start. Please refer to a proper video tutorial available in Udemy or other sites to get a excellent start. As your question is more objective, we cannot explain entire thing here. Get the knowledge about redux, so you can move the logic to redux reducers and actions. Also try to get to know about functional components where you can move the views and make the main component lean.

https://www.udemy.com/react-native-the-practical-guide/?start=0

You can take the above course for better knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's very clear which code is part of the view, and which is doing AJAX logic. The `userLogin` function is obviously not presentational; you can see from 10 feet away that the code is totally different-looking from the code above it.

However, it's a little bit tied to the rest of the app since it does UI-related things like show a `Toast`, and navigate.

One way to separate out this code would be to split the function in two. Move the AJAX call out to another (non-React) file, and remove anything related to React. It would just asynchronously return a result. Then the remaining part of the code in your view can respond accordingly (e.g. show a Toast, navigate, or call setState).

The next step might be to move the remaining bit of the function into a container component. That component would provide the login function, and store its results in its own state. Then it would pass the relevant parts of those results into the HomeScreen component. Something like:

```
import HomeScreen from './homeScreen';
import loginUser from '../apiClient';

class HomeScreenContainer extends Component {
  doLogin = () => {
    this.setState({loginInFlight: true});
    loginUser(userName, password)
    .then(result=>
      this.setState({loginInFlight: false, loginResult: result});
      if (result.loginSucceeded) {
        this.props.navigation.push('Settings');
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.setState({showLoader: false, loginError: true})    
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <HomeScreen 
        loginFunction={this.doLogin} 
        showLoader={this.state.loginInFlight} 
        shouldShowToast={this.state.loginResult.invalidLogin} 
        shouldShowError={this.state.loginError} 
      />
    )
}
```